# Search and remove <div> of particular class if they exist after the parent <div>

Tags: jquery

In the following case, when the `<span>` `class=add` is clicked, how can I check and remove any `<div>s` with the class `edit`, `flag`,`delete` ~ and many more, if they appear after the parent `<div>`.

These `<div>` need to be cleared if they exist, so a fresh `<div>` can be added there. I'm familiar with `remove()`, but I'm stuck with finding multiple `<div>` with the above classes and the parent part.

It is unlikely that all will ever be there, I've hard-coded them for this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Side bar poll thingy</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQueryCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").click(function() {
        // Find and remove all div's with classes flag, edit, delete, that may appear after the </div>
        // containing the <span> that was clicked 

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div class="h1" data-id="1">Teachers <span class="add" data-id="US01">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="flag">Flag</div>
    <div class="edit">Edit</div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="2">Who is your favorite Math teacher? <span class="add" data-id="US02">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="flag">Flag</div>
    <div class="edit">Edit</div>
        <br>
    <div class="h1" data-id="8">Restaurants <span class="add" data-id="US10">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="flag">Flag</div>
    <div class="edit">Edit</div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="9">Which is your favourtie restaurant in town? <span class="add" data-id="US20">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="flag">Flag</div>
    <div class="edit">Edit</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you pressed the `data-id="US01"` span which divs would you expect to be removed

Comment: You could remove the complete content of your "container" - i.e. with $("#container").html("");

Comment: pressing `data-id="US01"` would remove the `<div class="flag">Flag</div> <div class="edit">Edit</div>` that you see below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.flag, .edit, .delete').remove();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LjP2F/)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").click(function() {
        // Find and remove all div's with classes flag, edit, delete, that may appear after the </div>
        // containing the <span> that was clicked 

        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().nextUntil('div:has(.add)', '.flag, .edit, .delete').remove();
        //$this.parent().nextUntil('div:h1', '.flag, .edit, .delete').remove();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JFuwA/)